# Guitar Pro 6 – electric bass is quiet

Tags: bass-guitar, electric-bass-guitar, guitar-pro

First time I'm trying to write music in GP6 with bass track and I noticed that I cannot hear the electric bass. I checked out a many of its settings, but nothing helps me; all I can to check that it works is tune up to max the volume of electric bass. I hear very quiet sound of the bass but if I un-mute other instruments they sounds very loud with system volume maximum.

[image]

Comment: What kind of speakers are you playing it out of? Maybe your speakers don't have alot of low end?

Comment: @Grey I use MacBook Pro with Retina Display late 2013 and a sound quality is good. I can hear bass solo on HateBreed tracks so… a problem is a software.

Comment: If you're using the built-in speakers on a Mac Book Pro, all bass virtual instruments will fall partially underneath the frequency range the speakers can produce. This effect may be more noticeable for some instruments than others, and is definitely contributing to your problem.

Comment: @Grey you are right. Just put Apple EarPods in and hear a bass clearly, also with other instruments. Newer more compositing with built-in dynamics :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the lack of low end output that inbuilt speakers can provide, you often need to boost the overall output level of all low instruments such as bass guitars.

All electric string instruments on guitar pro have a default 7 band EQ effect in the second effects slot (Shown below). Normally you will need to boost the overall level on this to between +10 and +15 db to get the necessary volume.

[image]

This is much better than raising the track volume at the bottom of the interface as it distorts the sound less and can be raised further than the +6db that the alternative method provides you.

Hope that I have helped.

Comment: yeah i just seen that most “custom” EQs have 10% overall level. Just boosted it up and I am happy (mostly) with in-built speakers. But best I will use my studio headphones for authoring. It's about sound.

Comment: You can also use the bass amp's master volume, it's set to 7 by default.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem as well. What I do when I want to hear the bass clearly, I put the bass volume to max and lower the other volumes.

My speakers aren't really good, so that also has an effect on the voice of the bass.

Try to add more bass to your speakers if possible, or just lower the volume of the other instruments.

Guitar Pro isn't the best software, so the sound quality isn't really good either; don't have big expectations

Comment: sound quality is not a major issue when I authoring music. and yes, I want to switch to GarageBand or Logic Pro if I one of them has GP export support for my friends and band members.

Comment: and your answer is unacceptable because I almost cannot hear a bass when other instruments is muted and system volume is on a maximum.

Comment: Are you sure that your speakers are good ones? cos I can hear the bass, but not in great quality

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, it's likely because your speakers can't play bass well. In my experience, the best way to deal with this is to get better speakers or headphones and compose while using them.

I recently wrote a song with cheap earbuds and jacked the bass up so I could hear it. When I had a chance to hear the song on good speakers, the bass was overwhelming. If I had started with the good speakers, I would have made a better mix.